# Geometry Package - Layoutoffset: Distinction Between Odd and Even Pages Possible?

Tags: margins, double-sided, geometry

Currently I'm preparing a book for publishing. My printer wants a non-circumferential bleed around the pages, 0.125" at the top, bottom and outer side, but no bleed at the inner side. As far as I have seen until now, this is quite unusual, since a circumferential bleed is required normally.

Starting from this standard case, let us assume a book with a width of 7" and a height of 10". A circumferential bleed of 0.125" may easily be added using the `geometry` package and its `papersize`, `layoutsize` and `layoutoffset` option:

```
\geometry{papersize={7.25in,10.25in}, layoutsize={7in,10in}, layoutoffset={0.125in,0.125in}, ...}
```

For the case of a circumferential bleed this will work fine; in addition, no changes to the layout will happen, because the `layoutsize` is fixed to 7" × 10" (which is the later trim size). My intention is to preserve the later layout of the book, regardless of on what kind of paper size it is printed (paper size > layout size, of course). This is important to me because I need to generate a digital version of the book with *exactly identical* layout.

But this won't work for a non-circumferential bleed, since — as far as I know — `layoutoffset` is not able to distinguish between odd and even pages. For each odd (left) page, I would need

```
\geometry{papersize={7.125in,10.25in}, layoutsize={7in,10in}, layoutoffset={0.125in,0.125in}, ...}
```

and for every even page:

```
\geometry{papersize={7.125in,10.25in}, layoutsize={7in,10in}, layoutoffset={0in,0.125in}, ...}
```

Thus, I would appreciate any help regarding a possibility of modifying the original `layoutoffset` option of the `geometry` package to distinguish between odd and even pages — possibly by introducing two new package options `layoutoffsetodd` and `layoutoffseteven` to the `geometry` package (that would be the solution I'm most comfortable with; unfortunetely I'm not able by myself to do that).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You can define `bindingoffset=0.125in` and `geometry` will take care of odd and even pages.

Comment: @HarishKumar Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes, I could advance the `bindingoffset` parameter by 0.125", but then I would need to change the `layoutsize` parameter, too. My intention is to leave all document margins within the "layout" as they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither `geometry` nor `crop` can do what you want, without extensive patching of their inner workings. So I'm afraid that changing the `layout` parameter is the way to go, but with a *negative* binding offset, as you want the space in the outer margin:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  papersize={7.125in,10.25in},
  layoutsize={6.875in,10in}, % compensate for the negative binding offset
  bindingoffset=-.125in,
  layoutoffset={.125in,0.125in},
}
```

After all, it's a one time computation and you can then forget about it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I hoped that there is an easy (automatic) solution out there. But I'm okay with the manual calculation, if there is no easy way to patch the `geometry` package. So thank you very much for your solution.

Comment: This may work mathematically, but the `showcrop=true` will display the inner crop marks "incorrectly."

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly straightforward solution using `memoir`.

Note that to keep the answer focussed on the problem, I haven't tried to tune the size of the typeblock itself.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,showtrims]{memoir} % A5 quick-and-dirty
\usepackage{kantlipsum}      % Only to provide blind text
\setstocksize{10.25in}{7.125in}
\settrimmedsize{10in}{7in}{*}
\settrims{0.125in}{0.125in}
\checkandfixthelayout
\trimXmarks                  % Only to show the trimmings
% =================================================
\begin{document}
% =================================================
\kant[1-8]
% =================================================
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this solution would restrict me to using one single document class. I would rather construct a more general solution.

Comment: Fair enough. I confess I use `memoir` for everything except `beamer`