# How to indent everything but titles?

Tags: xetex, indentation, koma-script, scrbook

While passing `parskip=half` to `scrbook` removes all indentation, I (unfortunately) should indent everything by 10 mm, excluding chapter/section/... titles. How can this be achieved easiest? I was considering toying around with `bcor` and [putting section numbers into the (fake) margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196963/430), but that seems pretty complicated...

**edit** It's a bit late to add this, but ideally the titles' texts (not the numbering) would also start at that indentation and be aligned, i.e.

```
+----------¦-----------+------¦---------------+
|    1     A chapter   |    3 Another chapter |
|    1.1   A section   |      some text       |
|    1.1.1 A subsection|  3.1 another section |
...
```

That should be answered in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26905/430) though.

Comment: You should “outdent” titles, instead.

Comment: @egreg How? And will this work correctly for a `twoside` layout?

Comment: What do you mean? What should happen to titles in left-hand and right-hand pages?

Comment: @egreg "outdenting" titles would mean I should increase the margin, right? But in a `twoside` layout and using `\usepackage[inner=10mm, outer=20mm]{geometry}` how could I increase only the "left" margin no matter whether the page is odd or even? Would `bcor` work here?

Comment: I think you just want 2cm on either side, with titles sticking in the margin (inner on odd pages, outer on even pages) by 1cm.

Comment: @egreg No, on a left / even side that would increase the inner margin (i.e. on the _right_ side of text) and put the title stuck too far out on the left

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Second Update:**
If the chapter and section titles etc. should be aligned to the indented text you can use:

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  %chapterprefix
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\newcommand\secnumwidth{1.5cm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}
    {#3}
    {\@hangfrom{\hspace{-\secnumwidth}\makebox[\secnumwidth][l]{#2}}{#3}}%
}

\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#3}
    {#4}
    {\@hangfrom{\hspace{-\secnumwidth}\makebox[\secnumwidth][l]{#3}}{#4}}%    
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[
  layoutsize={\dimexpr\paperwidth-\secnumwidth\relax,\paperheight},
  layoutoffset={\secnumwidth,0cm},
  inner=1cm,
  outer=2cm,
  showframe,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Kapitel}
\blindtext
\section{Abschnitt}
\subsection{Unterabschnitt}
\subsubsection{Unterunterabschnitt}
\blindtext
\addsec{Abschnitt ohne Nummer}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Update:** It is better to use only the `geometry` options like @egreg showed in his answer. But the following code works also if the KOMA-Script option `chapterprefix` is used.

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  chapterprefix
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\RedeclareSectionCommands[indent=-10mm]{section,subsection,subsubsection}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \hspace{-10mm}\mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter
  \autodot\IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}

\renewcommand{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  #2\hspace{-10mm}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth+10mm}{\raggedchapter#3}%
}

\usepackage[
  layoutsize={20cm,27.9cm},% cut 1cm from the width
  layoutoffset={1cm,0cm},% put it in the offset
  inner=1cm,
  outer=2cm,
  showframe,
]{geometry}% from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280792/43317


\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

### [image]

**Original answer:**

Maybe something like that

```
\documentclass[
  chapterprefix
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\RedeclareSectionCommands[indent=-10mm]{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \hskip -10mm\mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter
  \autodot\IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}

\renewcommand{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  #2\hskip -10mm\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth+10mm}{\raggedchapter#3}%
}

\usepackage[inner=10mm,outer=20mm,nomarginpar
  ,showframe% shows the page layout
]{geometry}
\addtolength\hoffset{10mm}
\addtolength\textwidth{-10mm}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Kapitel}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\blindtext}
\section{Abschnitt}
\begin{center}
\blindtext
\end{center}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks!  I was about to suggest using [egreg's `geometry` options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280792/430), too, since the other version messed up with [my wallpaper layer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280160/430)

Comment: It's a bit late and probably should go to a separate question, but any chance you know how to have the section titles etc. be aligned with the indented text?

Comment: it was not requested, but I added `\setlist{leftmargin=5mm,labelwidth=5mm}` to decrease lists' indentations

Comment: I have added an example that have the section titles etc. aligned with the indented text.

Comment: Great update, thanks! I replaced `\newcommand{\secnumwidth}{1.5cm}` by `\newlength{\secnumwidth} \setlength{\secnumwidth}{1.5cm}` for better manipulability though. (I guess without arguments `\newcommand` with or without `*` are basically the same)

Comment: I just learned from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247033/430) that using `\newdimen` might be even better, since there's no stretch allowed. Then there's also no need to prepend `\the` anywhere

Answer (score 7):

You can use a trick I learnt some time ago: [using the layout feature of `geometry`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58006/4427)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  layoutsize={20cm,27.9cm},% cut 1cm from the width
  layoutoffset={1cm,0cm},% put it in the offset
  inner=1cm,
  outer=2cm,
  showframe,
}

\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{%
  \hspace*{-1cm}%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter \autodot\IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
}

\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\hspace*{-1cm}\thesection\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand{\subsectionformat}{\hspace*{-1cm}\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionformat}{\hspace*{-1cm}\thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\kant[1]

\section{A title}

\subsection{A subtitle}

\subsubsection{A subsubtitle}

\kant[2-4]

\section{A title}

\subsection{A subtitle}

\subsubsection{A subsubtitle}

\kant[5-6]

\section{A title}

\subsection{A subtitle}

\subsubsection{A subsubtitle}

\kant[7-15]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! I basically hybridized your answer and  [esdd's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280785/430) due to `\RedeclareSectionCommands` being shorter ;)

Comment: It's a bit late and probably should go to a separate question, but any chance you know how to have the section titles etc. be aligned with the indented text?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I think it can be done, but this would move the numbers much more than 1cm (look at the subsubsections).

Comment: Good point, so the overall indentation would have to be increased to, say, 2 cm... I think I saw another question about my additional request, but I can't find it right now :-/

Comment: ah, I meant [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26905/430)

Answer (score 2):

Setting `\leftskip` works for normal paragraphs, but not for lists, which require additional tweaking:

```
\RequirePackage{enumitem}  % If using a custom class, else replace with \usepackage{enumitem}
\AtBeginDocument{  % Or put this after \begin{document}
    \setlength{\leftskip}{10mm}
    \setlist[1]{leftmargin=15mm,labelwidth=5mm}
}
```

This is probably incomplete, e.g. I haven't tested tables and figures with this yet.